# How to integrate $\int \frac{1}{x \sqrt{8-x^2}}$

Tags: integration

I'm having problems finding the primitive function to $\int \frac{1}{x \sqrt{8-x^2}} dx$. I've tried to use the substitution $t = x^2-8$, but then I just get stuck with $\int \frac{1}{(8-t)\sqrt{t}} dt$ instead. Using the substitution $t = \sqrt{x^2-8}$ doesn't get me much further either.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What about $t=\sqrt8\sin(x)$? Thinking of $\sin$ and $\cos$ when encountering $x^2$'s under roots is usually a good idea

Comment: Try $x = 2\sqrt{2} \sin(t)$

Comment: i have had the same idea!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the substitution $x = \root \of{8}\sin u$ and $dx = \root \of{8} \cos u du$. Your integral becomes 
$$\int\frac{\root \of{8} \cos u }{\root \of{8} \sin u \root \of {8(1-\sin^2 u)} } du$$
$$=\int\frac{\root \of{8} \cos u }{8 \sin u \cos u} du = \frac{\root \of 8}{8}\int \csc u du$$

You can take it from here

Comment: Thanks! Neat substitution.

Comment: @chrstnsn You will actually soon discover that these trigonometric substitutions are quite common when looking at square roots of quadratic polynomials.

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

multiply by $x $ and put $t=x^2$ to get

$$\int\frac {dt}{2t\sqrt {8-t}} $$

then

$8-t=u^2$

to obtain a rational fraction.

Answer (score 0):

Formula -

$$\int \frac{1}{x \sqrt{a^2-x^2}} dx = -\frac 1a \operatorname{sech}^{-1}\frac xa + c$$

Now,

$$\int \frac{1}{x \sqrt{(\sqrt 8)^2-x^2}} dx$$

$$= -\frac 1{\sqrt8} \operatorname{sech}^{-1}\frac x{\sqrt8} + c$$

Answer (score 0):

You can perform a trigonometric substitution ($x=\sqrt{8}\sin u$, as in [Ziad Fakhoury's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2216074/159845)), but unless you can use the anti-derivative of $\tfrac{1}{\sin u}$ (from a table or by heart), this will lead to rationalization as well and you can do that straight away with one substitution:
$$\int \frac{1}{x \sqrt{8-x^2}} \,\mbox{d}x
= \int \frac{x}{x^2 \sqrt{8-x^2}} \,\mbox{d}x$$
Now $u^2=8-x^2 \iff x^2=8-u^2 \to x\,\mbox{d}x = -u\,\mbox{d}u$, and so:
$$\int \frac{x}{x^2 \sqrt{8-x^2}} \,\mbox{d}x \to \int \frac{-u}{\left(8-u^2\right) u} \,\mbox{d}u = \int \frac{1}{u^2-8} \,\mbox{d}u$$
Continue with a (simple) partial fraction decomposition to get two $\ln$'s.

Comment: Great complement to Ziad Fakhoury's answer above.